# Get list of orders that make up 80 percent the total items

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table that contains orders & number of items purchased under each order. I wanted to Select orders that make up 80% of the total purchase. I can easily get 80% of the orders by using `SELECT TOP 80 PERCENT Orders From tblOrder`  but it wouldn't be accurate since the other 20% could have a higher amount of total items.

Is there a way to get the orders that make up 80% (close to 80%) of the total number of items purchased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA would be simple and fast.

Create a recordset with the orders ordered by *total purchase* descending.

Loop the recordset once to obtain the sum of *total purchase*

Now loop the recordset once more, again adding *total purchase*, but stop when the sum has reached 80% of the amount from the first loop.

To create your list during the second loop, either copy each record to a new table or update a (new) field *Selected* to mark the records that add up to the 80%.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Added a new field in the table to Mark the orders that make up 80% of the total purchase. thank you!